# Cannot resolve @org.unit.Test in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, junit, junit4, assert

That's what pom.xml include:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.13.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

That's actual test code:

```
import org.junit.Assert.*; // Cannot resolve symbol 'Assert'

public class CalculatorTest {

    @org.junit.Test // Cannot resolve symbol 'Test'
    public void add() {
        Assert.assertEquals(5.0, 5.0, 0.01); // Cannot resolve symbol 'Assert'
    }
}
```

Building Project just says that it cannot fine symbol 'Assert'.
I tried Alt+Enter -> Add 'JUnit4' to classpath but it only doubles the dependency in pop.xml.

Comment: Have you tried `File->Invalidate Caches` Then check all boxes except `Ask before downloading...` then `Invalidate and Restart`?

Comment: Does the project build from the command line? `mvn clean package`. Does the project import complete without errors? Do you see JUnit libraries in the External Libraries node of the Project view? Does your source file reside in `src/test/java` and not in `src/main/java`?

Comment: @ritratt It worked! I don't know how to mark the right answer, but thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (and it appears it worked as per OP's comment):

1. `File->Invalidate Caches`
2. check all boxes except `Ask before downloading...`
3. `Invalidate and Restart`

Comment: It's really weird that invalidating caches helped in this case since it usually helps in the cases when the editor shows errors, while the code builds without errors. OP says the build failed as well, which usually indicates a problem with the dependencies, sources layout or some other Maven import specific bug and such issues are not fixed by invalidating the caches.